# Change DataGridTemplateColumn content style

Tags: c#, css, wpf

I want to change DataGridTemplateColumn content style, here is DataGridTemplateColumn code:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="50" MinWidth="30" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label Style="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonDown="LblEdit_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            
        </Label>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here is CellStype code:

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#F6F6F6"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF5750" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[image]

But the Label in DataTemplate not effect when row is select althought other cell is effect.

Any way to make it?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger sets the foreground color of the `DataGridCell` but not of the `Label`. You can reference the foreground color in the `Label` by adding this `Foreground` attribute to it:

```
<Label 
    Style="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" 
    Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Control}, Path=Foreground}"
    ... />
```